# std::thread constructor pass by reference when using a class member function

Tags: multithreading, c++11, constructor, rvalue, stdthread

I've done quite a bit of research on the new c++11 rvalue and carried over lvalue.
Here is a sample of what I have found and read:

> [what-does-t-double-ampersand-mean-in-c11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481539/what-does-t-double-ampersand-mean-in-c11)
>
> [how-stdthread-constructor-detects-rvalue-reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37242552/how-stdthread-constructor-detects-rvalue-reference)
>
> [stdthread-and-rvalue-reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32809192/stdthread-and-rvalue-reference)

I have also briefed myself on rvalue references

> [Move_Semantics](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2027.html#Move_Semantics)
>
> [rvalue_references](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_01.html)
>
> [A Proposal to Add an Rvalue Reference to the C++ Language](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2004/n1690.html)

Specifically, regarding the `std::thread` constructor, I found

> [how-to-create-a-thread-inside-a-class-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13205446/how-to-create-a-thread-inside-a-class-function/31382433?noredirect=1#comment80335836_31382433)

and used one of the answers to write some simple code

```
#pragma once
#ifndef CONSUMER_H
#define CONSUMER_H

#include "Mailbox.h"
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

class Consumer
{
private:
    Mailbox mailbox;
    std::thread consumer;
public:
    Consumer(Mailbox& newMailbox);
    ~Consumer();
    void operator()() { std::cout << consumer.get_id() << "starting\n"; }
    void start();
    void run();
};

Consumer::Consumer(Mailbox& newMailbox)
{
    this->mailbox = newMailbox;
}

void Consumer::start()
{
    consumer = std::thread(&Consumer::run, this); <-- need understanding
}

#endif
```

Checking the `std::thread constructor

> [std::thread::Thread](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread)

I observe a template that uses rvalue parameters.  I understand that a `std::thread` can be initiated through a simple example

```
void run(void) {std::cout << "I'm running";}

std::thread(run);
```

which appears straight-forward until I am inside a class whereby I need to do the following

```
consumer = std::thread(&Consumer::run, this); <-- need understanding
```

because I learned from Jonathan Wakely that run() is a non-static member function and has to be run on an object. How is the new thread supposed to know which object to call it on if you don't tell it?

This makes some sense but the need to pass by reference the class function doesn't since I have seen `A a; A&& ref = A()` possible.  I'm super confused about rvalues and just want to understand why the code I wrote above is necessary to pass the function to `std::thread`.

I feel certain I also don't understand variadic templates that well either which compounds my understand of the `std::thread` variadic template constructor.

Comment: The ampersand in `consumer = std::thread(&Consumer::run, this);` has nothing to do with references. It's an address-of operator, needed to form a [pointer-to-member-function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_member_functions)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Same thing; `int age = 45; int& rage = age is a reference to age` and a reference returns a pointer but the following `int age = 45; int* page = &age; int&& sage = page;` is not true so I'm still confused.

Comment: What do you mean by "and a reference returns a pointer"? It makes no sense to me, sorry. Neither `age` nor `rage` are pointers. And `int&& sage = page;` won't compile.

Comment: Best suggestion would be to go through some of the [good C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/2069064). If reading the `thread` constructor documentation isn't enough to explain what `thread(&Consumer::run, this)` does, we can't really help more than that.

Comment: @Barry Perhaps you can't help me.  I provided many references I have read through on rvalues.  It is a new concept in c++11 and its' treatment by authors like Stroustrup tend to make assumptions about what it is without explaining what it means have `var&&`.  I am reading Stroustrup's C++11 Programing Language, Lippman's C++11 Primer, and various resources about the net.  My understanding hasn't clicked with rvalues yet so I came to Stack for assistance.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik From Lippman @135 Lvalues and Rvalues - _The address-of operator (R 2.3.2, p. 52) requires an lvalue operand and returns a pointer to its operand as an rvalue_ - hence `int age = 45; int* page = &age`.  If my memory serves me correctly, K&R say the same thing in `The C Programming Language (ANSI @nd Edition)

Comment: Address-of operator can also be applied to a class member, resulting in a pointer-to-member. This wouldn't, of course, be mentioned in a C textbook, seeing as C doesn't have classes (nor pointers-to-member, which are distinct from "normal" pointers to object or pointers to function).

Comment: I discovered something interesting to me `int&& rref = 100; int val = *&rref;`  Does this imply that `rref` is a reference to a pointer and, by example, the `std::thread` constructor takes a forward to a function pointer?

Comment: No. You are very confused. `rref` is a reference to an `int`, and `&rref` takes its address, to create a pointer to an `int`. The symbol `&` has different meanings depending on context. In `int&` or `int&&` it declares a type "reference to int", but in `&rref` or `&Class::run` it forms a pointer by taking the address of something. These are completely different.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Would you like to make your comment an answer and expound upon it?  I'll accept your explanation because it helps my understanding.

Answer (score 4):

> I observe a template that uses rvalue parameters.

No, the `std::thread` constructor uses forwarding references, which means they can accept any type of argument and deduce either lvalue or rvalue references, depending on the argument type.

Read [forwarding references](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references) and [Universal References in C++11](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) (Scott Meyers introduced the name "universal reference" for these, but the official name is now "forwarding reference").

> This makes some sense but the need to pass by reference the class function doesn't

You're confused, `&Consumer::run` is not a reference of any kind. The symbol `&` as part of a typename means a reference, but when it apepars on the left of an expression it is the "address of" operator, which forms a pointer. In this case it is forming a [pointer to member function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_member_functions).

The expression `std::thread(&Consumer::run, this)` constructs a thread with two arguments, a pointer to the member function that should run in the new thread, and a pointer to the object that the member function will be called on. So in the new thread, something like this happens:

```
auto pointer_to_member_function = &Consumer::run;
auto pointer_to_object = this;
(pointer_to_object->.pointer_to_member_function)();
```

This is equivalent to running `this->run()`